# Unable to load DLL in WPF C# application

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, dllimport

I get following error message (VS2010) when running in debug mode my C# WPF appliction:

***"Unable to load DLL 'VCECLB.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"***

The code where this error occurs is (see hDevEnum):

```
namespace Imperx.FLExGrabber
{
public class Enumerator:IEnumerator
 {
    private IntPtr hDevEnum;

    VCECLB_EnumData enumData;
    /// Default constructor

    public Enumerator()
    {
        enumData.cbSize = (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(enumData);

        // Open enumerator handle
        hDevEnum = NativeFunctions.VCECLB_EnumInit();  <<--- Error message here!!!
    }

    /// Destructor
    ~Enumerator()
    {
        NativeFunctions.VCECLB_EnumClose(hDevEnum);
    }

 }
}
```

From the existing project, which uses a windows form application, it runs perfectly. Now I need to transfer this solution into a WPF-application. Therefore I am using the same machine (Win7/64ibt) with the same VS2010. The platform target is X64.

Question: Where I need to add the VCECLB.dll file into my project? I can not add it under references and therefore I put it into the folder "...\bin\x64\Release" - but no success.

When I check the VCECLB.dll with dependency walker I get following:
[image]

Does the question marks means that those dll's are missing? If so, why I can run the windows form project with the same VCECLB.dll?

Does anybody know how I can solve this issue? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to put the exact DLL (as shown in the error message) in the same folder as your .exe

Comment: Could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886310/loading-dlls-with-microsoft-visual-c-sharp-2010-express , i.e. trying to load a non managed dll (native) into a managed (.net) project,  if so check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx

Comment: @DrKoch I did this allready but it still gives me the same error message

Comment: @TommyGrovnes You are right but I do not understand how he add the dll into the project..! If I try to use to add it under "references" it does not work.

Comment: Check the comments on the approved answer, add it to project, copy etc (same as CodeInNet suggested)

Comment: @TommyGrovnes As mentioned allready, it does not solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two common causes for such an error:

1. The DLL that you are referring to is not on the DLL search path, or
2. The DLL that you are referring to is found, but its dependencies cannot be found.

Resolve problem 1 by putting the DLL in the same directory as the executable. Resolve problem 2 by making sure that all dependencies are installed. Typically this involves deploying the MSVC runtime that the DLL depends upon.

Comment: 1) I put the same .dll in the directory with the exe -> problem still exists
2) How do I find out if all dependencies are installed? When I run in VS2010 the project with the same dll it works.

Comment: Well, what do you know about this DLL? Where did you get it? Have you asked whoever supplied it to you what its dependencies are?

Comment: The dll comes from the vendor directly and therefore I have no further information. Does Dependency Walker helps in such cases (see above)?

Comment: Dependency walker would help. But only allows you to reverse engineer and guess. You should really contact the vendor, or consult the documentation that came with the DLL.

Comment: The problem was that - as expected from you allready - some dll's were missing. I've got some additional dll's from the vendor and now it is possible to compile the project without getting an error message! Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1):

You can put your VCECLB.dll any where in your solution (in root for example by Drag & Drop)

Then, once you added the file, click right on your file, choose **properties**

In Advanced three:

- Choose **content** in *Build Action*
- And **Always copy** in *Copy to output Directory*

to get something like the follwing:

[image]

Comment: Now it copies the VCECLB.dll in the same folder where my .exe is. Unfortunately I still get the same error message!

Comment: After seeing your update, You have to do the samething with VCECLB.dll dependencies (Referenced dlls by VCECLB.dll)

Comment: ok - the issue here is, that at the moment I don't know which are the dependencies of VCECLB.dll. The result of Dependency Walker does not look promising on that. I'll check with the vendor and keep this question updated.

Comment: Good, let me know when you find a solution :)

Comment: I've found the solution - see above!
Thanks for the help!